# Defragment a USB flash drive on Mac OS X

Tags: boot, osx

I frequently create bootable flash drives and many a time large files need to be defragmented in order to boot. On Windows I'd used Contig/WinContig, but I must use OS X for the same purpose now. Are there any free tools for defragmenting external drives for Mac or something more specifically for defraging single files?

Comment: What file system on the USB FD?

Answer (score 2):

I am quite confused why you would like to do it? Most convenient flash storage cells is very limited in writing times. So that flash file systems are designed to avoid to write into same cells frequently. But most disk de-fragment programs do, because they were designed to work with ordinary hard disk.

So if you really need to "de-fragment" your files on USB flash drive on purpose, I suggest you to choose an alternative approach:

1. Copy everything on the USB flash drive to your hard disk
2. Format your USB flash drive
3. Copy everything back into the USB flash drive

This approach will affect your USB flash drive's life as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the filesystem on the USB drive you can use one of the following tools to fsck the drive:

- fsck.ext3
- fsck.ext4
- fsck.vfat
- fsck.ntfs